# 16.04 - can't restart or shutdown

Tags: shutdown, restart

I have  a fresh ubuntu installation.
everytime I try to restart or shutdown, I got the following [image]

And that's it. I am forcing  shut down everytime.

Any idea what can I do to fix it?
or to gather more information to find out why this is happening.

Thank you

**EDIT**
some other information that might be helpful:
- I am dual booting with windows 10
- ubuntu is installed on an SSD partition that I shrinked through windows disk management
- there are other issues with the installation as well, like battery not charging even when plugged in but it is working fine in windows.

Comment: [This](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1732770) article/forum post might help... At least it seems to be somewhat related. Googling "clearing orphaned inode" may yield some useful information.

Comment: @0-60FPS, at least now I know what this output is. it is `fsck`.
but my issue is not the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem a few days ago...
This bug is common and there are a lot of solutions for it...
For me the solution was to update the kernel...
It was a kernel bug...Hope you can solve your problem too it was driving me crazy.
UPD: here this post helped me to update the kernel: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1872537
The one I use is 4.9.22-040922-generic Though as I said there are a lot of reasons why this happens this might not help you but you will never know if you don't try
:)

Comment: thank you,  could you provide some more details ?

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi here's an update.

Comment: I have no idea why this answer got downvoted, it was indeed a bug in the kernal and updating it solved my issue. Thank you.

Comment: No problem I'm glad you solved it because it was driving me crazy:)@Mhd.Tahawi